# Is it possible to stop an sql query from executing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I wish to ask if it is possible to stop an sql query during its execution. I wish to do this so that if someone else is executing the same query at the same time, the application would not jam. I am using visual studio c# as front end and oracle 11g as my back end

Comment: FYI, by "jam" you mean [deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock)

Comment: @Justin: Not really, deadlocks don't happen in queries (unless SELECT FOR UPDATE) is used.

Comment: IMHO this is something the server should take care of, and ot the cliente. Thus it's up to the DBA to find a mechanism to avoid this and it should be transparent to the programmer.

Comment: @Justin  No not deadlock

Comment: @m0skit0 ...good idea but I have to solve this :)

Comment: Same question for Oracle 10g, might want to check if it works for 11g: [Is it possible to kill a single query in oracle without killing the session?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466963/is-it-possible-to-kill-a-single-query-in-oracle-without-killing-the-session)

Comment: @Justin: queries do not lock **anything** in Oracle, unless you explicitly ask them to (using SELECT FOR UPDATE).

Comment: @mikespiteri: what is the nature of this query, and why would the application "jam" if 2 users ececuted it at the same time?

Comment: @Tony In that case what does the poster mean by "jam"?

Comment: @Justin: that's exactly what I want to know too!

Comment: @Justin, not only do queries not block anything, DML never blocks a query, either, unless the query is doing a lock as Tony states.

Comment: Also, when true deadlocks do occur, Oracle fairly quickly aborts one of the transactions with the error "ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource".

Comment: I'm wondering if he just has a slow running query that gets intolerably slow when more people are doing it at once.

Comment: @Tony Depending on a transaction's isolation level, you could have some queries waiting for other transactions to finish before executing.

Comment: @Null: yes, that's true.  I wonder if the OP will come back and answer any of these queries?

Comment: @Tony, maybe he's jammed up :-) In all seriousness, the concurrency and multi-versioning abilities in Oracle put it head and shoulders above most other RDBMS's out there.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the sql query in a pl/sql function and get a lock (with the dbms_lock package) before executing the select statement in the function/procedure (of course you have to release the lock at the end). This way you can serialize the execution of this function.

Another options is to use database jobs.

Answer (score 1):

What query are you doing where this is a problem? Most likely that can be optimized to solve whatever issue you're having.

It's not really realistic to do this because for every query that comes in, you'll have to see if someone else is already running it first. That's going to create a lot of overhead and complexity in the system.

Answer (score 0):

well definitely you can KILL QUERY query_id. To test open console mysql -u root -p, perform a long query and ctrl + c ;) but well, I cannot think of any practial way of using it, tracking queries you could potentialy want to kill etc. however if you really needed it to save the world, you will probably succeed

Comment: KILL QUERY is a MySQL command.  It does not work with Oracle.

Comment: @APC haven't seen the tags! my bad!