# Java - Stop a long running thread which accesses database

Tags: java, multithreading

I start couple of threads, but I do not have their references to stop by signalling or something.
For example, I can't pass a variable like `running=false` to those threads, because I do not have their references, but have their names.

I'm using a `ThreadGroup` and always I have the reference of it. So I can do something like this. Seems to be it doesn't work.

```
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[threadGroup.activeCount()];
    int count = threadGroup.enumerate(threads);
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        threads[i].interrupt();
    }
```

This is a sample of my thread.

```
    public void run{

         try{
             //myDAO.getRecords();
             //this takes 30seconds to 60
             //returns about 3 millions of records

         }catch(Exception e){
             //log
         }
    }
```

When this thread is executing, I want to stop it in the middle.
Anyway batabase query is running, but I want to stop getting results.

Still I'm getting results even I call `interrupt()`.
Are there any other ways to do this OR have I done anything wrong ? Ultimately the task is to cancel a long running sql query from Java.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Calling `interrupt` for a thread that is say waiting for the query output has no affect as most of the JDBC drivers are immune to the status. It will still remain blocked and the query will keep executing.

Calling `cancel` will kill the connection and the thread executing the query in the database. For once in a while it is ok but it also kills the connection. This can create serious problems and will soon turn out to be the bottleneck.

An alternative but a working solution would be to get the the `ID` of the thread executing the procedure/query (on the database side) and to call:

```
KILL QUERY id;
```

> KILL QUERY terminates the statement that the connection is currently executing, but leaves the connection itself intact.

To know the ID, right In the procedure, have the first line as: `SELECT CONNECTION_ID();`. This Id can be used to terminate it.

Comment: Note that described query kill approach is MySQL-specific. Here is Oracle trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466963/is-it-possible-to-kill-a-single-query-in-oracle-without-killing-the-session

Answer (score 9):

If your DAO is using JDBC and you want to stop a query that is in progress, you could have another thread call [`cancel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#cancel%28%29) on the Statement:

> void cancel()
>               throws SQLException
>
> ```
> Cancels this Statement object if both the DBMS and driver support aborting 
> an SQL statement. This method can be used by one thread to
> cancel a statement that is being executed by another thread.
>
> Throws:
>     SQLException - if a database access error occurs or this method is 
>     called on a closed Statement 
>     SQLFeatureNotSupportedException - if the JDBC driver does not support
>     this method
> ```

You might have the run method delegate the DAO call to another thread, and have it listen for interruption and call cancel.

Here's [a post where somebody's using a Spring JdbcTemplate to cancel a query](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?60493-How-to-cancel-a-database-query-using-Spring-DAO). So it is working for someone out there (using MySQL).

Also [see this answer describing how queries get canceled in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/659063/217324).

Comment: I have no idea about this, but I'm going to look into it.

Comment: BEWARE. cancel also kills the connection. If you are using it a lot, then it will degrade the performance

Comment: @Jatin: letting a query run when it's not needed is also bad for performance. But it is a good thing to be aware of that the connection will be lost.

Comment: @NathanHughes a better thing would be to use `Kill_query id` (if at all you manage to know the `id`). This does not kill the connection and only instructs the db thread to stop executing the query (more mentioned in below answer). I came across this situation and this looks the best approach

Answer (score 3):

> Still I'm getting results event I call interrupt(). Are there any other ways to do this OR have I done anything wrong ?

When your thread got interrupted you need to check in `run()` whether your thread pass `isInterrupted()` condition .

I think `interrupt` is the best way to achieve this because `an interrupt will unblock some blocking IO` and synchronization requests. A bespoke solution cannot do this.

Comment: I'm doing it right now, but I thought there might be a better way.

Comment: I'm not sure about this at all, but I would guess that `interrupt` would not unblock a database connection.  I know it does not unblock a socket connection.

Answer (score 2):

Your thread code needs to catch the `InterruptedException`, and set the interrupted flag on your thread. See [this JavaSpecialist newsletter](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue056.html) for more info.

```
  try {
    // ... 
  } 
  catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // very important
    break;
  }
```

The thread to interrupt must not be computationally-bound. That is, it should be performing network IO, sleeping etc. in order to catch and respond to the `InterruptedException`. A loop such as `while(1) {}` won't be interruptable.

Comment: It gives me this `Unreachable catch block for InterruptedException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body` compilation error.

Comment: I guess your DAO catches exceptions (and most likely won't handle this scenario properly)

Comment: `IntrruptedException` can be caught if there is a `sleep()` call.

Comment: Exactly. InterruptedException only actually interrupts a small number of things (like sleep). In general, you need to use the **isInterrupted()** method to detect interrupts.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will interrupt thread running indefinately ,after interruption thread will forced to stop.

```
         @Override public void run() 
           {   // infinite loop to process

                   while(true) // your variable 
                   {                              
                      // We've been interrupted: no more processing.
                      if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                         return;
                       }
                   }

            }
         }
```