# Cancel SQL Statement with JDBC

Tags: java, sql, tomcat, jdbc

I am stuck with this problem here. I am running an application on my Tomcat Application Server. As a frontend I am using an HTML site with javascript in it, in the backend i am using Java.

When the user clicks on a button several sql queries are made, one after another. Now I want to provide the ability to cancel this query if the user wants to.

I already checked if my jdbc driver and the database are compatible for the `cancel()` method and this is just fine.

Here is my code :

```
PreparedStatement stmt = null;

public void runQuery(String query) {
    Connection con = getConnection();       

    try {
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
        stmt.execute();
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(stmt != null && !stmt.isClosed()) {
            stmt.close();
        }

        if(con != null) {
            con.close();
        }
    }
}

public void cancelQuery() {
    try {
        if(stmt != null && !stmt.isClosed()) {
            stmt.cancel();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So the user clicks the run button => `runQuery` is executed and stmt is initialized/overriden with the query which needs to execute.

Then the user clicks the cancel button => `cancelQuery` is executed.
Unfortunately I sometimes get a NullPointerException because stmt is null. But it should not even call cancelQuery if the stmt is null ?! 
Here is the stacktrace:

```
    Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.doCancel(SybStatement.java:646)
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.cancel(SybStatement.java:614)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.cancel(DelegatingStatement.java:269)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.cancel(DelegatingStatement.java:269)
    at de.package.util.DBHelper.cancelQuery(DBHelper.java:82)
.....
```

Any idea why this keeps producing an exception ? How can I cancel the statement the right way ?

**EDIT:**
I had allook at the link in the comments and now running the cancel() method from a different thread. However the NullPointer still happens. This is how i call the cancel() method now:

```
public void cancelQuery() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new SQLCancelRunnable(stmt));
        thread.start();
}

    public class SQLCancelRunnable implements Runnable {
    PreparedStatement stmt;

    public SQLCancelRunnable(PreparedStatement stmt) {
        this.stmt = stmt;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(stmt != null) {
        try {
            System.out.println(stmt);
            System.out.println(stmt.toString());
                stmt.cancel();
                System.out.println("canceled");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       }
   }
}
```

**EDIT2**
Found my answer the problem was the finally block of the runQuery() method. Because I closed statement & connection the NullPointer was thrown.
I now removed this block but this, of course, leads to huge resource leaking. Anyone who can guide me in the right direction how to close my resources properly ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/16589497/217324

Comment: @NathanHughes please have a look at my edited question. the link didn't brought the overall solution :(

Comment: I would say, why worry about it? Just catch NullPointerException.

Comment: Since NullPointerException is a runtime exception i should not catch it but avoid it right ?

Comment: @dehlen , check out the updated answer to know how to release resources

Comment: @dehlen: i didn't claim it would, otherwise i'd have closed this as a duplicate.

Comment: @dehlen IHMO you should keep it simple! 1) Put back the finally clause which is absolutely essential because it releases the resources 2) In my opinion all that's happening is that in some cases, as you have discovered, the stmt is being closed right after the if(stmt != null) line. Keep it simple, forget other threads, which are complicated, just catch the NullPointerException and return.

Comment: well ok I'll go with this answer. It looks like its working for me now.. Just tried to write correct code and not just "code that seems to work". But for now this will be the solution I'll take.

Comment: suspect race condition in the "close vs. cancel" methods if one closes at "about the same time" as cancel is called some weirdness could happen.  That NPE is not "in your code" it seems to be "in the heart of their code" when you call cancel.  Also `con` is guaranteed to never be null.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;

    public void runQuery(String query) {
    Connection con = getConnection();       


    try {
    stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
    stmt.execute();

    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if(stmt != null && !stmt.isClosed()) {
            stmt.close();
        }

        if(con != null) {
        con.close();
        }
    }

}

public void cancelQuery() {
    try {
        if(stmt != null && !stmt.isClosed()) {
            stmt.cancel();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Try this. I have added a Generic Exception just after the SQLException.

Cannot say this is a very clean solution but it will ignore the null pointer exception which is possiblly raised by stmt.close() statement.

Comment: Since this is kind of the answer I go with now, I'll mark you as accepted, although It might not be the cleanest solution..

Comment: For anyone finding this question later: Please do not write code like this! Take look at the [answer by user "dag"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58117608/373074) further down in this thread instead.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to synchronize statement closing:

```
public void runQuery(String query) {
    ...
    try {
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

        stmt.execute();
        ...
    finally {
        synchronized(this) {
            if(stmt != null && !stmt.isClosed()) {
                stmt.close();
            }
        }
    }
}

public void cancelQuery() {
    synchronized(this) {
        if(stmt != null && !stmt.isClosed()) {
            stmt.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

between every statement another thread may execute some kind of code, so a simple if is not sufficient to be sure the state of the world is as you expect it to be.

Synchronizing on `this` may not be the best option, but as the `stmt` may be null we can't use this object.

Edit: If the code starting the query is asynchronous you'll also have to be prepared for calls to `cancelQuery` even before your statement is prepared.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [Statement.cancel()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#cancel())

As Java Docs Says

```
void cancel()
            throws SQLException
```

> Cancels this Statement object if both the DBMS and driver support
>   aborting an SQL statement. This method can be used by one thread to
>   cancel a statement that is being executed by another thread.

You can also set [setQueryTimeout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setQueryTimeout(int)) if query execution passes a threshhold time

```
java.sql.Statement.setQueryTimeout(seconds)
```

**Update**

Don't forget to [Rollback](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#rollback()) the transation

> Anyone who can guide me in the right direction how to close my
>   resources properly ?

this is what for finally block was invented

```
finally{
//Release All Resources
}
```

> The finally block always executes when the try block exits. This
>   ensures that the finally block is executed even if an unexpected
>   exception occurs. But finally is useful for more than just exception
>   handling — it allows the programmer to avoid having cleanup code
>   accidentally bypassed by a return, continue, or break. Putting cleanup
>   code in a finally block is always a good practice, even when no
>   exceptions are anticipated.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but basically you are describing what I already tried. I close all my resources in the finally block and I run the cancel() method from a different thread.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Apache DB-Utils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/) it makes this kind of problems disappear and you can simply write something like:

```java
} finally {
    DbUtils.closeQuietly(resutlSet);
    DbUtils.closeQuietly(preparedStatement);
    DbUtils.closeQuietly(connection);
}
```

Comment: Is this still commonly used in 2021? Or has there something more modern developed in the meanwhile?

Comment: as of today one should use try with resources blocks, which may still throw SqlExceptions but they at least handle the NPEs and Exceptions raised inside the try or in the finally correctly (remember never to throw exceptions in finally blocks?)